# I use "Action to make Phone Call" but I need to make a called automatically for 5 or 10 min

Tags: android, call

This is an example
But I need to make a called for 5 minutes or 10 minute automatically. How I can make it?

```
  Intent in=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("0000000000"))
  try{
     startActivity(in);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use broadcast receiver and set action as Time change.And set Alarm for every 5 min to send action to broadcast receiver.
Add this code in your activity:

```
PendingIntent service = null; 
Intent intentForService = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), YourService.class);
final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
final Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
time.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
time.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
time.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
if (service == null) {
 service = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
                    intentForService,    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        }

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, time.getTime()
                .getTime(), 60000, service);
```

Create Broadcast Receiver and add code for Make Call in onReceive() of receiver.

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d("BroadcastReceiver", "debut receive");

    Intent in=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("0000000000"))
    startActivity(in);

    }
}
```

I hope its helpful to you.
Happy Coding..

Comment: I think it's work and don't forget to add permission on you manifest file: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

Comment: Hi, Thanks very much!!!. And How I can answer a call automatically? Can you help me ?